# Reducing noise on a bike trainer

Tags: noise, trainer

I have a JetBlack M1 Pro Mag Trainer. I use my road bike on it, with slick tires. However it is still pretty noisy.

What are the ways to reduce noise from a magnetic trainer?

Comment: Are you trying to reduce the noise for others in your house or for yourself when you are riding? I'll ride with headphones to reduce the noise I hear from my trainer.

Comment: Like I do in my car -- turn up the radio.

Answer (score 2):

I found that by using trainer specific tires the noise gets lower (see [these](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/?s=tyre%20trainer) for example).

Another thing that usually helps is to put a carpet under the trainer.

Anyway, the major culprit for noise is the trainer itself, so I fear you should buy another model of trainer if, even by using carpet and proper tyres, it's still too much noisy.

Answer (score 2):

You can get 3'x3' squares of interlocking foam in packages of four that I put under my trainer.  I got mine at Canadian Tire and I imagine you'll find them at Home Depot or some similar home supply place.